# Joining two collection in MongoDB using Meteor JS

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I am trying to connect two collection: Books and Poems. One book can have some poems. I have to get just one book with all related poems.

I expect that result will have "poems_join" field, which contains joined collection, but "poems_join" does not exists. No error displayed.

```
export default withTracker(props => {
    const bookSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('mybooks');
    return {
        editedBook: Books.findOne({ _id: props.editBookId },
        {
          $lookup:
            {
              from: 'poems',
              localField: 'poems.id',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'poems_join'
            }
        }
    ),
    bookLoaded: bookSubscription.ready()
};
})(BookEditor);
```

Publication code is here:

```
Meteor.publish('mybooks', function (bookId) {
   return Books.find({ userId: this.userId, _id: bookId },
   {
    $lookup:
    {
      from: 'poems',
      localField: 'poems.id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'poems_join'
    }
  });
 });
```

What do I wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your publication code? That's where the join should happen

Comment: Hi Fred, I have just added the publication code. I would appreciate your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to handle this (and a way I use in multiple applications) is to use the [composite publications](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) package.

To use it, all you need to do is store a reference to the book the poem belongs to on the poem document.

Example:

```
const poem = {
    title: 'A great poem',
    author: 'William Blake',
    belongsTo: 'R84dizM7dnhPbrFX8',
}
```

Then, you can simply create the following composite publication:

```
import { publishComposite } from 'meteor/reywood:publish-composite';
import Books from '../books.js';
import Poems from '../poems.js';

publishComposite('bookAndAllPoems', function(bookId) {
    return {
        find() {
            return Books.find({ _id: bookId });
        },
        children: [
            {
                find(book) {
                    return Poems.find({ belongsTo: book._id });
                },
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

This is a really simple way to send joined data to the client in Meteor, and works really well.

You could event publis more children documents that belong to the Poems if you wish.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a great solution, but be careful as it can get really slow with a lot of records. Publishing them separately or aggregating would probably be faster. Be sure add an index on the `poem.belongsTo` field as well.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I will check it out. I am little bit sceptical regarding "This package is great for publishing small sets of related documents. If you use it for large sets of documents with many child publications, you'll probably experience performance problems." But I am not sure what is large and small. Have to test it. Is this a better way to join then using $lookup?

Comment: I haven't used $lookup so I'm not sure which is better. I also haven't dug in to the source code to see if that's how the publish composite package works. In my experience the publish composite package is fine for sending 100 linked documents

Comment: Hei Sean, I tried to get it work, but without success. I made a new case with more description of collections. Could you please take a look at this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306048/create-join-of-two-collections-in-mongodb-using-meteor-js Thanks! :)