# Create join of two collections in MongoDB using Meteor JS

Tags: mongodb, join, meteor, collections

I have following data structure:

Collection books:

```
{
  _id: "ajafsoaifj3341",
  title: "Hello World",
  poems: [
      {
        id: "12fjenofnoi23",
        addedAt: "2018-03-12...."
      },
      {
        id: "563jdfb34jfrr",
        addedAt: "2018-03-10...."
      },
      {
        id: "78a1ewqeqweq",
        addedAt: "2018-03-08...."
      }
   ]
}
```

Collection poems:

```
{
  _id: "563jdfb34jfrr",
  title: "How to Join",
  author: "Smith"
  addedAt: "2017-12-21..."
}
```

I need to join these two collections to get the title of the poem. Something like:

```
{
  _id: "ajafsoaifj3341",
  title: "Hello World",
  poems: {
    id: "12fjenofnoi23",
    addedAt: "2018-03-12....",
    title: "How to Join"
  }
}
```

I fond an example like this:

```
//SERVER
import { Poems } from '../imports/collections/poems';
import { Books } from '../imports/collections/books';

Meteor.publish('booksWithPoems', function (bookId) {
  const book = Books.findOne({ _id: bookId });
  return [
    Books.find({ _id: bookId }),
    Poems.find({
      _id: {
        $in: book.poems.id
      }
    })
  ];
});

//CLIENT
export default withTracker(props => {
const bookSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('booksWithPoems', props.editBookId);
return {
    editedBook: Books.findOne({}),
    editedPoems: Poems.find({}).fetch(),
    bookLoaded: bookSubscription.ready()
};
})(connect(mapStateToProps, {    
    ...
})(withRouter(BookEditor)));
```

But this.props.editedPoems is undefined. What is wrong here?

Maybe this are better ways to do this. I would appreciate if you could help me both with server and client code. I am quite new in Meteor/Mongo world.

And the last comment. I do not need all data from Poem documents, just "title". Thanks!

Comment: you need something unique to join. look at this on how to do joins in mongodb https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Can you add the schema of `Poem` and `Book` please? I assume you want to get all poems related to a book, right?

Comment: You are right, Jankapunkt. I have just updated the structure of the Poem collection. I hope it is more clear now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your publication has the following problematic part: `$in` excpects an array, while `book.poems.id` is a String value on a single poem. What you want, however is an array of all ids in `book.poems`.

This is also the cause while the other subscription (`editedBook`) receives some data and `editedPoems` not. Subscription reflect only those documents, that have been found in the last execution of the publication method.

In order to get this correct you need to first `map` Poems ids and set this array as value for `$in`:

```
Meteor.publish('booksWithPoems', function (bookId) {
  const book = Books.findOne({ _id: bookId });
  return [
    Books.find({ _id: bookId }),
    Poems.find({
      _id: {
        $in: book.poems.map( p => p.id ), // ["12fjenofnoi23","563jdfb34jfrr","78a1ewqeqweq"]
      }
    })
  ];
});
```

Now it should select all poems, whose id fits one of the ids provided in the array, assigned to `$in`.

I have not checked the client code and the way you join the data, but I think this mongo query selector is the main issue here.

More to read on $in: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: Thank you, Jankapunkt! Now it is working. It was OK with client code. I have just added { fields: { title: 1 } }) to get the title only. ;-)

Comment: Do you have any comments about performance? I think it must be quite good. Are there any better way to deliver better performance?

Comment: You could avoid the map functiin by just storing the _id values in `book.poems` if there is no explicit need to store documents on other documents you are usually good by referencing by Id. This has in the first place more effort in DB design but adds a good scalability to it.

Comment: I am saving id to each poem which in the book. Is it not the same? One poem can be in the different books.

Comment: Now I am trying to add a new poem to the book, and collection 'books' is comming back with a new poem. It'a right. But collection 'poems' is not updated and does not contants the title of the added poem. Is it just 'books' which reactive? I expected that 'poems' will return added title.

Comment: Only if it's exactly the book you reference by bookId, other poems would be ignored.

Comment: Yes, I add to the same book, the list of the poems is updated, but subscription "editedPoems: Poems.find({}).fetch()" return the same titles without the added poem. Title should be added to Poems also, right?

Comment: If you don't restrict the fields in the publication it should be there, yes. If you change the structure on books.poems to only id strings you have to make sure to add them on the client using proper mapping. I hope I do not confuse you now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166925/discussion-between-podeig-and-jankapunkt).